# match vectors in matrix python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, probability

I am new to python and programming in general.

I want to create a matrix from 2 vectors for example when I have
a = [1, 2, 3] and b = [4, 5, 6]
I want to get a matrix that has the same rows in as the vectors but the vectors are in seperate colums.
m =[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]

I am looking for a method how to do this as I have more complex vectors in my code then in my example.
I want to do the same for the vectors probability_of_winning and probability_of_losing.

```
import numpy as np
p = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01, dtype = float)  


alpha = input("alpha = ") 
alpha = np.zeros((1, 100)) + alpha 

def w(alpha, p):
    return np.exp(-(-np.log(p))**alpha)

w = w(alpha, p)

def P(w):
    return np.exp(np.log2(w))
     
probability_of_winning = P(w)
probability_of_winning = np.round([probability_of_winning], decimals=2) 
probability_of_winning_in_percent = probability_of_winning * 100

probability_of_losing = 1 - probability_of_winning
probability_of_losing_in_percent = probability_of_losing * 100
```

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pythonic and numpy-style, not requiring **any** loops, appending or other costly operations:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])

np.vstack((a, b)).T
```

Also works for mixed types and large amounts of vectors, f.i. `a` and `b` being `np.arrays` and `c` and `d` being python `list`s:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
c = [13, 21, 12]
d = [19, 33, 77]
# add all to a tuple
arrays = (a, b, c, d)
# and stack
np.vstack(arrays).T
```

Instead of `np.vstack(arrays).T` the more general `np.stack(arrays, axis=1)` can also be used.

Comment: thank you for the example. it is much shorter than the other suggestions. when I try doing it the same way: arrays = ( probability_of_winning, probability_of_losing)
matrix_of_probabilities = np.vstack(arrays).T  it only displays the first row of the matrix. I am not sure why since the array captures each element of my float vectors.

Comment: You are welcome! It is also more *pythonic* since it avoids loops (basic python programming rule: avoid loops whenever possible. loops are slow and ugly), returns a numpy array and should be much faster in general than explicit loops and appending. :)

Comment: i still have a problem. in you example i get exactly the matrix i want, but when i try it whith my float vector, by first adding them in a tuple and then using np.stack(arrays).T  i dont get the matrix for each element of the float vector but only the first. do you know what i need to change?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do `a` and `b` look like? Only a is float? And which output do you get?

Comment: for a and b I want to use the floats probability_of_winning and probability_of_losing from the code I entered in the question.  when i use alpha=0.5  and use the codes you provides then i get np.vstack(arrays).T = ([0.05, 0.95]) but with this the matrix is not complte because the floats have a length of 99

Comment: your probability vectors are of `ndim==3`, thus it may be related to false indexing? Because `np.vstack(arrays).T` works for your code. Try either squeezing your probability vectors or the stacking result: `np.vstack(arrays).T.squeeze()`. If this does not solve the problem, please open a new question with a detailed input and output and send me the link.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [7, 8, 9]
d = [10, 11, 12]

def horizontal_matrices(*args):
    res = []
    for i in range(len(args[0])):
        col = []
        for j in args:
            col.append(j[i])
        res.append(col)
    return res


print(horizontal_matrices(a, b, c, d))
# [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Comment: This is not using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])

arr = np.empty((0, a.shape[0]-1), int)
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    to_append = np.array([[a[i], b[i]]])
    arr = np.append(arr, to_append, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[[1 4]
 [2 5]
 [3 6]]
```

Comment: Why preallocate and then append? If you preallocate, select the final size right away and then assign values to array by indexing.